# Find dependents of ROS Message and Service statically

Tags: ros, ros-comm, ros-fuerte, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There used to be [a command `rosmsg users`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmsg#rosmsg_users) back in `ROS Electric` (!) or earlier that seems to return the list of ROS Messages that depend on the given Message type. Is there a ROS-way of achieving the same in the post-Electric era?

Also curious why `rosmsg users` was dropped if anyone remembers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286343/find-dependents-of-ros-message-and-service-statically/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was removed in [ros/ros_comm@b6cfd8aa](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/b6cfd8aa0b3ccac94bb540b0859708f1a420a451). Ken's commit message:

> rosmsg: deleting users command, which won't work in install tree

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1